# WD My Book World Edition (white light) shares/connection are being lost

Tags: networking, external-hard-drive, network-shares, nas

I have a very weird problem with WD My Book World Edition (white light). It is connected to the router (CAT6) and so is a Windows 10 desktop. There're a few shares on WD that are used by the desktop (as well as an Android phone via WiFi). If I shutdown and restart the WD - for a while shares are visible and accessible - both from Windows and Android. But after a while they simple disappear. And it looks like connection to the WD is broken somehow, when I try to load the configuration Web page - it times out (even though I can still ping the IP address of the device). If I again shutdown and restart the WD - everything works for a while again. Any idea what's going on and how to address it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the "Troubleshooting" instructions on p179 in [My Book World Edition User Manual](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705013.pdf)?

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the link, it is helpful. Though I don't see exactly the same problem (works for a while and then stops) I might try some of the recommended steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently the solution set the IP for WD as static on *both* the router and WD itself. I had it as manual/static on the router, but in WD settings it was set to DHCP. Once I set that to manual IP as well everything seems to be stable.